# Refactor similar Linq Queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Is there any sense to refactor these methods? How to do it?

```
    public IEnumerable<Game> GetGamesByGenre(string genre)
    {
        return Games.Where(x => x.SubGenre.Genre.GenreName == genre);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Game> GetGamesBySubGenre(string subGenre)
    {
        return Games.Where(x => x.SubGenre.SubGenreName == subGenre);
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

You can introduce a new parameter called `propertySelector`:

```
public IEnumerable<Game> GetGamesBy(Func<Game, string> propertySelector, string genre)
{
    return Games.Where(x => propertySelector(x) == genre);
}
```

You's call the original methods like this respectively:

```
GetGamesBy(x => x.SubGenre.Genre.GenreName, someGenreName)

GetGamesBy(x => x.SubGenre.SubGenreName, someSubGenreName)
```

But IMO, if it's just these two methods, with this little code as their bodies, is not very worth refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way

```
public IEnumerable<Game> GetGames(string? genre, string? subGenre)
{
    return Games.Where(x => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(genre) || x.SubGenre.Genre.GenreName == genre) 
                   && (String.IsNullOrEmpty(subGenre) || x.SubGenre.SubGenreName == subGenre));
}
```